# Can't accurately collate data from list with an integer

Tags: python, list, if-statement, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to call a search of a list with `if` statements and then add values to a co-ordinate that I can call to draw an object in turtle. Similar solutions are welcome, but I really would like to know where I am going wrong in my thinking here:

```
fixed_data_set_01 = [['Competitor A', 'Right'],
                     ['Competitor A', 'Down'],
                     ['Competitor A', 'Down'],
                     ['Competitor A', 'Left'],
                     ['Competitor A', 'Up']]


def list_searcher():

    global fixed_data_set_01
    d = len(fixed_data_set_01)
    f = 0 # looping variable to search through index
    y = 0 # defining y coord
    x = 0 # defining x coord
    
    for lister in range(d):
        
        print(fixed_data_set_01[f])
        f = f + 1
        p = fixed_data_set_01[f]
        
        if 'Up' in p:#if up is in the move set add value to y coord for competitor
            y = y + 90
            print(y,x)# testing
                 return y
    
        if 'Down' in p:#if down is in the move set add value to y coord for competitor
            y = y - 90
            print(y,x)# testing
                return y

        if 'Left' in p:#if left is in the move set add value to x coord for competitor
            x = x - 120
            print(y,x)
                return x
        
        if 'Right' in p:#if right is in the move set add value to x coord for competitor  
            x = x + 120
            print(y,x) # testing 
                return x
        
list_searcher()
```

Comment: sorry I'm pretty new to this if it helps i realize i don't need the return after each if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time making sense of your code and explanation.  The best I could figure is that the data set should generate a path that the competitor follows, so I've implemented that below:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

fixed_data_set_01 = [
    ['Competitor A', 'Right'],
    ['Competitor A', 'Down'],
    ['Competitor A', 'Down'],
    ['Competitor A', 'Left'],
    ['Competitor A', 'Up'],
]

def list_searcher(competitor, data_set):

    path = [(0, 0)]  # starting coordinates

    for who, *directions in data_set:

        if who != competitor:
            continue

        x, y = path[-1]

        if 'Up' in directions:  # if Up is in the set add, value to y coord
            path.append((x, y + 90))
        elif 'Down' in directions:  # if Down is in the set, subtract value from y coord
            path.append((x, y - 90))
        elif 'Left' in directions:  # if Left is in the set, subtract value from x coord
            path.append((x - 120, y))
        elif 'Right' in directions:  # if Right is in the set, add value to x coord
            path.append((x + 120, y))

    return path

screen = Screen()

path = list_searcher('Competitor A', fixed_data_set_01)

turtle = Turtle()

for position in path:
    turtle.goto(position)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

If that's *not* the case, provide more code and more explanation of what you're trying to do.